# What are some good books for studying about Carbon Nanotubes?

Tags: resource-recommendations, nanoscience

Ok, so I am trying to computationally model a Carbon Nanotube FET and I need to know a lot about the actual equations and PDEs(Partial Differential Equations) involved while modeling such a material. I had taken a course in material science in my sophomore year , but that just covered the basics of CNTs and its applications.

I would really like to know if there are some **good** books out there that give an in depth understanding about CNTs ( structure, properties, behavior in presence of Fields, Equations and PDEs, Fabrication and applications, etc)